# Google Cloud Run: COPY fails when changing source folder from ./ to build

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

```
$ gcloud builds submit --tag gcr.io/projectname/testserver
// ... works fine until the COPY step:

Step 6/7 : COPY build ./
COPY failed: stat /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder653325957/build: no such file or directory
ERROR
ERROR: build step 0 "gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker" failed: exit status 1
```

That build folder listed above, `/var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder653325957/build`, is not a local folder. Does Cloud Builder create a temp folder in that format?

How do I get it to copy my local `build` folder?

I also tried `COPY ./build ./` but the CLI output was the same

Dockerfile below.

```
FROM node:12-slim

# Create app folder
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# Install app deps. Copy the lock file
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install

ENV SCOPES=removed \
    SHOPIFY_API_KEY=removed \
    SHOPIFY_API_SECRET=removed \
    CLIENT_APP_URL=removed

COPY build ./
CMD ["node", "server.js"]
```

Comment: Is the `build` directory listed in your `.gcloudignore` or `.gitignore` file?

Comment: @DustinIngram I have not setup `.gcloudignore`. Yes, `/build` is listed in `.gitignore` (including the preceding `/`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `gcloud` command uses the `.gitignore` and `.gcloudignore` files to determine which files and directories to include with the Docker build. If your `build` directory is listed in either of these files, it won't be available to copy into your container image.

Comment: Why is this the case though? I want to exclude build files from my git but move them from one container to the other

Comment: By default, your `.gcloudignore` is probably recursively including your `.gitignore` file. If you want them to behave differently, then you can remove the line in `.gcloudignore` which includes `.gitignore`.

Comment: I actually completely ignored the problem by takin build on my local machine and pushing that image to gcloud